# TCL How to have as a class member an array (Itcl)

Tags: arrays, tcl, incr-tcl

I want to have an array as a private class member. I use Itcl package.

For lists and other simple variables I was writing:

```
itcl::class MyClass {
private variable m_myVar ""
private variable m_myListVar {}
..........
```

Now what I can do for array member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should declare the variable as normal using  `private variable m_myArray` and then in the constructor initialize it as an array `array set m_myArray {}`